# What version of Wildfly corresponds to JBossEAP 7.4?

Tags: jboss, wildfly

No available version found in the Red Hat website. I found a website (http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-eap/what-is-the-difference-between-jboss-eap-wildfly-and-jboss-as/) but data is only until JBossEAP 7.3.

Comment: Is Wildfly 22 the compatible version for JBoss EAP 7.4? I found the info here [https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/WildFly+22.x.html]. Can someone please confirm?

Comment: Asking the same question again isn't going to improve your chances of an answer.  Wildfly gets updates many times a year.  JBoss is released much less often.  7.4 is the current release.  They will take bug fixes from the various Wildfly versions and integrate them in but there is not a 1 to 1 mapping.  What is the real problem you're trying to solve?  If you're trying to port then the most recent of each is likely your best bet.